# Why can't I comment on an answer?

Tags: support, comments

Here's the link: [How to monitor Windows host with Nagios?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104045/how-to-monitor-windows-host-with-nagios#comment89073_104049)

I want to ask the the person who answered the question to specify the syntax to monitor windows server events, but the add comment box does not appear. Why? Is it because I don't have a high enough reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it on one, you don't have the required [50 reputation](https://serverfault.com/privileges/comment) to comment on posts that are not your own.

That's a very old question, you may want to [ask your own](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) but please have a go yourself and tell us what you tried and why it didn't work as you expected.